# Java Theory: Classes Design for Currency, Futures and Metals Analysis 1

Tags: java, object-oriented

This is a continuation from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761207/java-theory-classes-design-for-currency-futures-and-metals-analysis

I have created 2 classes for now.
1) Historical Data 
2) Futures.

Here is the Code:
It does the following:
Takes in a file, checks if it is a file, dynamically creates an array based on the size of the file then it prints it out as a string. As you can see this is procedural still. It works but I am not using OOP principals

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/*
 * This will allow me to uploadFutures historical csv data into an arraylist
 * I then want to perform analysis on it
*/


public class Futures extends HistoricalData{


// absolute path of my file
File esFuturesData = new File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Stock Project/Tick Data Source Files/TextFiles/Completed/test.txt");


// need to declare an list to loop through it
public ArrayList<E> myList = new ArrayList<E>();

// need a method to see if the file can be read.
public boolean isaFile()
{
return esFuturesData.isFile();
}

// need a method to get the size of the file  ..
public int sizeofFile() throws IOException{
// variable z for size of file
    int z = 0;
if(isaFile()){
    //  read in the file esFuturesData and store it in object reader
BufferedReader reader = null;
try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(esFuturesData));
        // need to find out how many rows are in the file
            while(reader.readLine() != null)
            {
            //when there is new line increment z by 1
            z  +=1;

            }               
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println();
    }
finally{
    if(reader != null){
        reader.close();
    }
}
}
else{
    System.out.println("This is not a file");
}
return z;
}



// need to create a dynamic String array based on the size of the file
public void createArray(){
    // reset the rows of the file to 0.
    int rowCount =0;
    // create a testData array based on the number of rows method and that is of 4 columns
    myList = new ArrayList[sizeofFile()][5];
    // we need to read in the file..
    // catch any errors..
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(esFuturesData));
    // we need to create a line of type String to store what we are putting through it..
    String line = null;
    // need to keep reading until there is nothing left.
    while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
    // we need to put the line into the array testData
    StringTokenizer p = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
    // while there is something to read
    while(p.hasMoreTokens()){
    // loop through the first column and add a 1        

        for (int columnCount = 0; columnCount<1;columnCount++){
        // need to convert to string representation of an int

            myList[rowCount][columnCount] = "0";
        }

    // loop through the columns
    for (int columnCount = 1; columnCount<5;columnCount++){
        myList [rowCount][columnCount] = p.nextToken();
        //System.out.printf("%s", testData [x][y]);
    } // end of for loop
    rowCount++;
    } // end of while loop
    } // end of other while loop        
    } // end of try braces
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println();           
    } // end of catch
} // end of create array braces

// method that prints the file as a String
public void printArrayAsString(){

    // Some Housekeeping
    System.out.printf("  ID");
    System.out.printf(" Date");
    System.out.printf(" Time  ");
    System.out.printf("  Price");
    System.out.printf("   Volume");
    System.out.println();

    // need a loop to go through each row number    
        for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount < myList.length; rowCount++ ){
    // print out each row number
    //  System.out.printf("%s", x);
    // print out a space
        System.out.printf("   ");
        {
        for(int columnCount = 0; columnCount < 5; columnCount++ ){
        System.out.printf("%s", myList [rowCount][columnCount]);
        System.out.printf("   ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: @Bobby as per your very useful comments I have updated my code.

Comment: @Bobby as per your very useful comments I have updated my code. I tried using the ArrayList option but running into problems.  I want to add a new unique key to each unique row before I parse it. Then I want to upload my esFuturesData object to the ArrayList after I parse it. my thinking may be wrong on this. what is the best format to have the data in the ArrayList as I will want to do analysis on the date, time, price and volume at a later stage. The data format is as following for the futures data: date (ddmmyy),time,price,volume example: 021211,154611,00901.75,2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your indentation, brace-style and white-space usage is all mixed/messed up, fix that (hit "Format Code" in your favorite IDE if available).

---

```
// reads in a esfutures file and stores it as esfuturesdataobject
```

[Java documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) normally looks like this:

```
/**
 * This is an important variable
 */
private String awesomeness = null;
```

That allows IDEs and other systems to pick up on them and f.e. display them directly to you.

---

```
File esfuturesdata = new File("C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//Stock Project//Tick Data Source Files//TextFiles//Completed//test.txt");
```

- [Variable names in Java should be lowerCamelCase](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).
- You've got a hardcoded path here, is that really what you want?
- Windows uses backslashes `\` which need to be escaped, slashes `/` don't need to be escaped, so it's one *or* the other:

  ```
  C:\\Users\\Administrator\\..
  C:/Users/Administrator/...
  ```
- Consider adding a visibility modificator (`private`, `public`) for clarity.

---

```
// need to declare an tesdata Array for looping through my data
String [][] testData;
```

Consider if a `List<T>` might be more interesting in this case.

---

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(futuresdata));
```

Readers and similar should be closed after usage. On possible design to do this is this:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    // Usage goes here.
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // Exception handling goes here.
} finally {
    if(reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

---

```
catch (Exception e)
```

Do not catch generic Exceptions, catch only those which are necessary and handle them gracefully. Also consider if you may want those thrown, because at the moment the application will happily continue on if the file could not be read for *any* reason.

```
System.out.println("e");
```

What is that supposed to be?! Not to mention that errors should to stderr, which is `System.err.println()`.

---

```
// reset the rows of the file to 0.
int x =0;
```

If that variable holds the number of rows, then please also give it a meaningful name, like `rows` row `rowCount`.

---

```
}// end of futures class brackets
```

If your code is well structured and correctly intended, such comments are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the current class design. What does `HistoricalData` look like?

Think about the different things you are working with, what they represent, and what you want to do with them. Then model them as classes.

For example, I see something that represents a line in the CSV file. I can see it has things like ID, Date, Price, etc. Currently, these appear to be just strings in an array. Consider creating a class to represent this, with properties of the appropriate data type (for example, `java.util.Date` for the date & time). Maybe something like `HistoricalDataElement`(?). Maybe you can come up with a better name. What would you call the data in a single row in the CSV file?

It may also make sense to create a separate class to represent a collection of `HistoricalDataElement`s. This could be a good place to put some functions that operate on the set of data as a whole. You'll have to decide if this makes sense for your scenario. Maybe you will have multiple classes to do different kinds of analysis.

You should also consider separating the parsing into it's own class.

Here is a very rough outline of what I am thinking:

```
public class HistoricalDataElement {
    private String id;
    private Date dateTime;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private long volume;
    // getters/setters
}

public class HistoricalData {
    private List<HistoricalDataElement> historicalDataElements;
    public long doSomeAnalysis() {...}
    public long doSomeOtherAnalysis() {...}
    // etc
}

public class HistoricalDataParser {
    public HistoricalData parse(File file) {...}
}
```

Comment: @ Joe thanks. let me work on what you have given me along with other comments from this thread and previous thread. Im very new to this so am not sure what the best way is but i like the idea of having seperate variables for each of the data elements in my file. I am going to spend more time on working on my classes design and specifying what each is meant to do and will be open to suggestions on each.